# D3.js - generating a drag event in Jasmine programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, d3.js, jasmine

I have a line chart component written using D3 and Angular. It has draggable bars used to change the scale of x axis. Now I am trying to test the component using Karma/Jasmine. I have a trouble triggering drag event in the unit test. 

Other events like mouseover and click are triggered just fine. I think it's the synthetized implementation of "drag" event in d3 which causes issue. 
Here is the code I use to trigger dragging (such code fires a correct d3 drag event on a test html page, but fails inside a unit test).

```
    var leftBar = element.find(".left-bar")[0];
    var evObjStart = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evObjStart.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 1, 12, 320, 12, 320, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var evObj = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evObj.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window, 1, 100, 320, 100, 320, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var evObjEnd = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evObjEnd.initMouseEvent("mouseup", true, true, window, 1, 200, 320, 200, 320, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    leftBar.dispatchEvent(evObjStart);
    leftBar.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    leftBar.dispatchEvent(evObjEnd);
```

I found out that only the first event is correctly dispatched (leftBar.dispatchEvent(evObjStart)).
Other two events are not dispatched at all. leftBar variable is correct 100%. I am totally lost on where to search the error. 

P.S. I tried generating "dragstart", "drag" and "dragend" events, but they are not handled properly by d3 in browser (did not work in a basic test example in console). Mousedown/mousemove/mouseup sequence works correctly in browser, but only mousedown is dispatched in the unit test. Will be very grateful for any help or ideas.

Comment: I think you would simplify your life a lot if you just called the handlers directly with mocked arguments and trusted that the browser vendors properly implemented event handling.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! My use case is a bit more complex. Actually, my code is located within an angular directive, so handlers are not accessible from outside. Making them accessible would actually break the concept of using this directive as a separate plugin (which is not meant to affect external html or variables). I thought of writing a "test-only" directive version with handlers visible from outside, but this is kind of conflicting with the idea of unit testing if I have one component for distribution and another for tests. Hope my explanation makes sense)

Comment: You can make the handlers accessible from outside by doing a variety of things. For instance adding them as a member or static property to your directive's controller. Which can be retrieved with $controller if it's been properly registered.

Comment: I think I'd go about this by creating directives to do d3 mouse event bindings, *then* using those in a directive that is more of a template/controller construct. It's possible the one directive you made is trying to do too much, which is making it hard to test.

Comment: Thank you! Will research that now. You are right, currently I have all code inside one directive. Angular is used to deliver/update the data, and all processing is done inside with d3. I will try to redefine the architecture, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't an answer, I hope this helps.

Here's a way you can break your handlers off into something testable.

Add them as members of your controller like so:

```js
app.controller('MyDirectiveCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.dragHandler = function() {
    // do stuff
  };
});

app.directive('MyDirective', function(){
  return {
   controller: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
      drag.on('drag', ctrl.dragHandler);
      d3.select(elem[0]).call(drag);
   }
  }
});
```

Then to test:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    // create the controller
    var ctrl = $controller('MyDirectiveCtrl', {
       $scope: mockScope
    });

    // call the handler
    ctrl.dragHandler(mock, args, here);

    // assert some difference
    expect(mock).toBe(differentSomehow

);
```

Comment: Ben, thank you so much for your quick and efficient responses. Your idea deepened my understanding of Angular, thanks! My supervisor wants me to keep stuff inside the directive for flexibility and independence, so I'll search for a way to alter it differently. PS I hope you don't mind if I still leave the question open, maybe someone happens to trigger drag event for d3.

Comment: I don't mind at all that you leave the question open.

Comment: Tell your supervisor "Ben Lesh says you're crazy" :P haha. If something is hard to test, it's because it's poorly constructed. You're going to have to expose those handlers one way or another and get them tested. Testing the DOM directly is very hard, and very brittle. If you *must* go that route, look into creating Protractor tests, although I'm not sure how well it will work with drag and drop.

Comment: XD thanks, Ben! my supervisor is a great guy, I think he also has a good point (it's me who doesn't get it right, most likely). I will go on reconsidering the architecture. Thank you for your effort put into this question, I greatly appreciate it! Will consider Protractor, for sure.